# XCODE: presentViewController from UITableView does not show back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I've been reading tutorials, questions and answers here (Stackoverflow) and there but I can't get it. It doesn't work, so I must have missed something.

The situation is: from a table view, once the user selects a row, a new view with information is displayed. Not a detail view, I'd like to embed a navigation controller but I don't know how.

The code I wrote:

```
...
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    UIViewController *viewController =nil;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case termaSection:
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:{
                    viewController = [[TermasChavasqueira alloc]init];
                    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
                    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                                  target:nil
                                                                                  action:nil];
                    navController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
                    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
                    //[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                    break;
                }

                default:
                    break;
            }

        default:
            break;
    }
```

What I obtain on TermasChavasqueira.xib is a NavigationBar, with no back button. The command [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil]; works fine adding the button on Interface Builder, but its a regular button, not the arrowed one.

The next piece of code does not work either:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can't show the typical backbuton with this way. It comes by default when you display a viewcontroller using `pusviewcontroller:` method.

Instead of doing this, add a `UIToolBar` to the T`ermasChavasqueira.xib` and add a barbutton for dismissing the view.

Write the action of `UIBarbutton` like:

```
- (void)dismiss:(id)sender
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If you still need to use `UINavigationController` change:

`navController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton`;

to

```
navController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: That's what I did, I add a Navigation Bar with two buttons  (one of them to dismiss the view)and title, and a UIToolBar to open another view.

Comment: @Luis: I said to add UIToolbar not UINavigationbar, there is a huge difference between both